# How to add assembly code to the prologue and epilogue of all functions with the instrumentation code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, instrumentation, gcc-plugins

everyone.
I'm working on a C project and I need a way to add assembly code in the prologue and epilogue of every function in the source code.

Let me give you an example.

This is the source code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char buff[20];
    int a = 20;
    printf("Variable a: %d\n", a);
}
```

The relative assemly code is this:

```
0x0000000000001169 <+0>:    endbr64 
0x000000000000116d <+4>:    push   rbp
0x000000000000116e <+5>:    mov    rbp,rsp
0x0000000000001171 <+8>:    sub    rsp,0x40
0x0000000000001175 <+12>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x34],edi
0x0000000000001178 <+15>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x40],rsi
0x000000000000117c <+19>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
0x0000000000001185 <+28>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
0x0000000000001189 <+32>:   xor    eax,eax
0x000000000000118b <+34>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24],0x14
0x0000000000001192 <+41>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24]
0x0000000000001195 <+44>:   mov    esi,eax
0x0000000000001197 <+46>:   lea    rdi,[rip+0xe66]        # 0x2004
0x000000000000119e <+53>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x00000000000011a3 <+58>:   call   0x1070 <printf@plt>
0x00000000000011a8 <+63>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x00000000000011ad <+68>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
0x00000000000011b1 <+72>:   xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
0x00000000000011ba <+81>:   je     0x11c1 <main+88>
0x00000000000011bc <+83>:   call   0x1060 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
0x00000000000011c1 <+88>:   leave  
0x00000000000011c2 <+89>:   ret
```

Now what I want to do is find a way to automatically add my assembly code in the prologue and epilogue when I compile it. And then get a situation like this:

```
0x0000000000001169 <+0>:    endbr64 
0x000000000000116d <+4>:    push   rbp
0x000000000000116e <+5>:    mov    rbp,rsp
0x0000000000001171 <+8>:    sub    rsp,0x40
0x0000000000001175 <+12>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x34],edi
0x0000000000001178 <+15>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x40],rsi
0x000000000000117c <+19>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
0x0000000000001185 <+28>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
// instrument code here...
0x0000000000001189 <+32>:   xor    eax,eax
0x000000000000118b <+34>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24],0x14
0x0000000000001192 <+41>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x24]
0x0000000000001195 <+44>:   mov    esi,eax
0x0000000000001197 <+46>:   lea    rdi,[rip+0xe66]        # 0x2004
0x000000000000119e <+53>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x00000000000011a3 <+58>:   call   0x1070 <printf@plt>
0x00000000000011a8 <+63>:   mov    eax,0x0
// instrument code here...
0x00000000000011ad <+68>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
0x00000000000011b1 <+72>:   xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
0x00000000000011ba <+81>:   je     0x11c1 <main+88>
0x00000000000011bc <+83>:   call   0x1060 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
0x00000000000011c1 <+88>:   leave  
0x00000000000011c2 <+89>:   ret
```

I've done a lot of research on this. And I couldn't find anything that would explain how to do it.
I know that the gcc compiler offers the `-finstrument-functions` option to instrument the functions, but is not what I need. That's because that option involves adding these two functions:

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *func, void *callsite); 
void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *func, void *callsite);
```

that in the relevant assembly turn out to be calls to those functions, and that's not what I want.

I've read that through a gcc plugin maybe you can get this result, but the documentation is really poor.
I also read something about [DynamoRio](https://dynamorio.org), but I think what I need is a static and not dynamic instrumentation system.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You could compile to `.s` files and do text manipulation on them, *before* assembling.  You can add stuff before every `ret`, if you avoid destroying RDX:RAX and XMM1:XMM0 (the possible return-value registers).  Although that won't catch `jmp` tailcalls.  Note that tail-duplication optimization can give a function multiple exit points.  Also calls to noreturn functions I guess, if you want to get fancy.

Comment: This seems an XY-problem. Working at the assembly level also seems wrong: adding new instructions would require you to fix metadata and offsets. Why the GCC instrumentation framework is not working for you? Are there a lot of functions, isn't easier to manually add two macros in the code? Why not dynamic instrumentation?

Comment: about macros: of course I could insert it manually, but for the project objectives I need it to be inserted automatically. Do you think dynamic instrumentation can solve this problem?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Offsets are only nailed down in the machine code, not asm.  if you modify the `.s` output before assembling, the assembler can calc the right offsets and `.size` metadata based on labels.  So it's at least plausible, depending on how much of a problem it is to mishandle corner cases.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, for some reason I was thinking about machine code. Maybe it was the disassembly that brought me in "edit-the-binary" mode.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I had the same thought at first that the question was thinking about editing the binary, and yeah showing disassembly instead of compiler output is what gave that initial impression for me, too.

Comment: I mean you could always hack it into the compiler, like [this stack alignment verification code in comment 11 of GCC bug 40838](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40838#c11). Not saying you should, just that you could.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I was wondering whether you were able to figure out the solution to this question.